# Why is package sourced from AWS CodeArtifact rebuilding upon install?

Tags: python, aws-codeartifact

I'm sourcing a custom python package that I uploaded to CodeArtifact but noticed that the .whl file gets rebuilt every time I install it.  I would not have expected that to happen as I uploaded the pre-built .whl file to the respository. I would have assumed that it would install like any other python package.  The build has drastically increased the environment build time making it unfeasible to source this package from my repository, partially defeating the purpose. I haven't yet been able to find any documentation that explains this behavior.  I'm not sure if this is normal or if there's something I can do to ensure that the package is installed like any other.  I would appreciate any information that can be provided.